# How to link to another webapp but still respect AAM

Tags: sharepoint-designer

We use SharePoint 2010.

We have 2 web applications, one for normal content and the other for mysites - AAM is set up so these web apps are accessible from outside our network. We would like to be able to have a link to a users mysite (e.g. http://mysite) in a summary link web part. When we hardcode this link, when a user connects from outside and is placed in the Internet zone, the link does not change to the internet zone of the mysite web application.

Is there a way of dynamically doing this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Generally speaking the default zone URL should be the most available, i.e. with a FQDN.

Can you not just hard code the FDQN http://mysite.domain.com and ensure that the URL is accessible internally and externally?

Comment: Hi, thought about doing that, but one is http and the other https :( I'm guessing from this that there isn't an easy way of doing this!